# A variable is not saved as data on a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, variables

I am trying to make a variable that changes as the loop goes on in R, so I used the paste() function in a loop, to make a variable that changes accordingly. Here is my code:

```
#dataframe
df1 <- structure(list(lex_1 = c("гей", "гей", "гей", "гей", 
"гей", "гей"), lex_2 = c("лесбиянка", "бисексуал", 
"-пропаганда", "трансгендер", "-активист", 
"пропаганда"), fxy = c(256, 56, 33, 40, 22, 109), fx = c(3035, 
3035, 3035, 3035, 3035, 3035), fy = c(1000, 214, 33, 1125, 25, 
14989), log2Dice = c(11.02, 9.14, 8.46, 8.3, 7.88, 7.63), logDice = c(11.94, 
10.63, 10.16, 10.05, 9.76, 9.59), Dice = c(0.126889714993804, 
0.0344721452754694, 0.0215123859191656, 0.0192307692307692, 0.0143790849673203, 
0.0120949844651576)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

df2 <- structure(list(lex_1 = c("лесбиянка", "лесбиянка", 
"лесбиянка", "лесбиянка", "лесбиянка", 
"лесбиянка"), lex_2 = c("бисексуал", "гей", 
"трансгендер", "транссексуал", "ге", 
"гомосексуалист"), fxy = c(102, 256, 65, 34, 253, 
35), fx = c(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000), fy = c(214, 
3035, 1125, 294, 10830, 1305), log2Dice = c(11.43, 11.02, 9.97, 
9.75, 9.45, 8.96), logDice = c(12.22, 11.94, 11.21, 11.05, 10.85, 
10.51), Dice = c(0.168039538714992, 0.126889714993804, 0.0611764705882353, 
0.0525502318392581, 0.0427726120033812, 0.0303687635574837)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# loop sekaligus
df3 <- c()
df3 <-c(df3, list(df2, df))
angka <- 0

for (df in df3){
  df_dokumen <- df
  colnames(df_dokumen)[3] <- "fxy"
  colnames(df_dokumen)[4] <- "fx"
  colnames(df_dokumen)[5] <- "fy"
  df_dokumen <<- df_dokumen %>%
    select(1:5) %>%
    mutate(logDice_2 = round(14 + log2((2 * fxy) / (fx + fy)) ,2),
           logDice = round(14 + log((2 * fxy) / (fx + fy)) ,2),
           Dice = (2 * fxy) / (fx + fy))
}
```

But, out of all variables, the variable df_dokumen seem to be just gone out of nowhere. I have tried to use the <<-, but it yield nothing.

Any troubleshooting for this?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

I am expecting the variable df_dokumen to not be gone, even by using <<-, it does not seem to work for me.

Comment: Your use of `<<-` here is completely unnecessary _here_ and typically bad practice in general. There are several things to look at in this question, but unfortunately lacking reproducibility, there's very little we can do. Please consider adding sample data (via `dput` please) and just as clearly expected output given that sample data. Please read and heed: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: btw, your screenshot shows that `df_dokumen` is present with 239 rows and 8 columns. What am I misunderstanding? (This of course is defiant in the face of your `select(1:5)`, but ... again, cannot reproduce atm.)

Comment: Are you running this inside a function or `local(.)` block?

Comment: Hey @r2evans! I have fixed the problem using assign() function. The problem is that I overwritten the variable, hence its gone

Comment: The use of `<<-` and `assign` are too often indicators of mistaken design. If it works for you then good luck, but ... those two are rarely used correctly, and if you have to ask then it is typically "not correct".

Comment: Im not sure I am understand what you mean by mistaken design, it worked for me just fine. Mind explaining more @r2evans?

Comment: Yes. R works well (and most packages rely on) _functional design_, where things change when you explicitly assign them. The use of `assign` and `<<-` work in side-effect and can be the source of many problems. It breaks reproducibility, for starters, and if/when I deal with packages that start changing variables in the calling/global environment, I tend to find ways to either fix what it is doing or just switch packages. In the R realm, it is generally accepted that a function/expression should only change what was explicitly passed to it and nothing more.

Comment: This discussion goes quickly into the pros and cons of referential versus copy-on-write access. There are clear exceptions in R where in-place changes to data is by-design, such as `data.table`, but most things do not do that. There are also clear areas where working in side-effect is normal, such as rendering plots, exporting data to files, and serving files (`plumber`, `shiny`, etc). In general programming, however, "future you" should appreciate it when a function you define does not change data out from under the caller.

Comment: As your question reads, it does not demonstrate that it is within a function, so there is nothing that `<<-` or `assign` can do that is different from the simpler `<-`. The fact that it did apparently fix things for you is an indication that we don't see the whole picture. I'm glad you have something working, I don't want to project my coding standards on you, so perhaps keep moving forward until you find another problem. My guess is that your problem here is really about something else you don't know about (nor do I) that using `assign` just masks. Tread carefully!